# how can i add video on res file?? the raw file dont appear to me in res file? and should the video be defined in R.java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

http://javatech.org/2011/01/discovering-android-embedding-video-in-an-android-application/

it's a link to solve this issue, but i don't have the "raw" file in the "res" as the solution posted. is it because its not defined in R.java?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to create a folder. just right click res and select New, then Folder and name your folder as "raw". Best of luck